# How to convert multiple images in to separate layers in one EPS file using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have set of multiple images, which I need to merge in to one eps file as separate layer. Is it possible via ImageMagick? how?

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay images with the `-composite` command, you can give it at shot:

```
$ convert image1.jpg image2.jpg ... imageN.jpg -composite output.esp
```

See https://imagemagick.org/script/composite.php